# Android studio not able to show xml files correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android studio suddenly showing autogenerated codes in xml files. I have tried invalidate cache/restart, but it doesn't solve the problem. I had also tried clean project and rebuild it but it also doesn't work. Even though everything shows correctly in a editor like sublime text.
Here is my code of one of the xml files that android studio showing.

[image: Code as showing in android studio]

[image: Code as shown in sublime text editor]

`/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

```
package com.airbnb.lottie;

public final class R {
    private R() {}

    public static final class anim {
        private anim() {}

        public static final int abc_fade_in = 0x7f010000;
        public static final int abc_fade_out = 0x7f010001;
        public static final int abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom = 0x7f010002;
        public static final int abc_popup_enter = 0x7f010003;
        public static final int abc_popup_exit = 0x7f010004;
        public static final int abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom = 0x7f010005;
        public static final int abc_slide_in_bottom = 0x7f010006;
        public static final int abc_slide_in_top = 0x7f010007;
        public static final int abc_slide_out_bottom = 0x7f010008;
        public static final int abc_slide_out_top = 0x7f010009;
    }
    public static final class attr {
        private attr() {}

        public static final int actionBarDivider = 0x7f030000;
        public static final int actionBarItemBackground = 0x7f030001;
        public static final int actionBarPopupTheme = 0x7f030002;
        public static final int actionBarSize = 0x7f030003;
        public static final int actionBarSplitStyle = 0x7f030004;
        public static final int actionBarStyle = 0x7f030005;
        public static final int actionBarTabBarStyle = 0x7f030006;
        public static final int actionBarTabStyle = 0x7f030007;
        public static final int actionBarTabTextStyle = 0x7f030008;
        public static final int actionBarTheme = 0x7f030009;
        public static final int actionBarWidgetTheme = 0x7f03000a;
        public static final int actionButtonStyle = 0x7f03000b;
        public static final int actionDropDownStyle = 0x7f03000c;
        public static final int actionLayout = 0x7f03000d;
        public static final int actionMenuTextAppearance = 0x7f03000e;
        public static final int actionMenuTextColor = 0x7f03000f;
        public static final int actionModeBackground = 0x7f030010;
        public static final int actionModeCloseButtonStyle = 0x7f030011;
        public static final int actionModeCloseDrawable = 0x7f030012;
        public static final int actionModeCopyDrawable = 0x7f030013;
        public static final int actionModeCutDrawable = 0x7f030014;
        public static final int actionModeFindDrawable = 0x7f030015;
        public static final int actionModePasteDrawable = 0x7f030016;
        public static final int actionModePopupWindowStyle = 0x7f030017;
        public static final int actionModeSelectAllDrawable = 0x7f030018;
        public static final int actionModeShareDrawable = 0x7f030019;
        public static final int actionModeSplitBackground = 0x7f03001a;
        public static final int actionModeStyle = 0x7f03001b;
        public static final int actionModeWebSearchDrawable = 0x7f03001c;
        public static final int actionOverflowButtonStyle = 0x7f03001d;
        public static final int actionOverflowMenuStyle = 0x7f03001e;
        public static final int actionProviderClass = 0x7f03001f;
        public static final int actionViewClass = 0x7f030020;
        public static final int activityChooserViewStyle = 0x7f030021;
        public static final int alertDialogButtonGroupStyle = 0x7f030025;
        public static final int alertDialogCenterButtons = 0x7f030026;
        public static final int a`
```

Comment: Add some screenshot of the problems.

Comment: I have updated my question and added screenshots.

Answer (score 5):

Just copy the existing project to another folder and reopen the project with android studio, it will display normally again.

This problem happen to me today, when I opened a java file android studio showed me the XML file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22442347)

Comment: i am sorry, i can not add screenshot here, because that day when this happen , i also searching for the answer here, and i found similiar case(but i think not 100% the same), but i fix my problem by my self, and i just want to share it here(but i don't take screenshots of my case so i can not add screenshots here). i am just do the programming for fun , i am not a real programmer, and do not have programmer background, i can make my own android app because of learning from the code shared here by stack overflow user, so i am not an expert, sorry if my answer do not help

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't clear the cache of android studio, then try to clear it.

```
C:\Users\user_Name\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me. First Close Android Studio.

and Go to

**C:\Users\your_user_name\ .AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches**

Delete the caches folder.

And open the android studio. And your project is now open without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should be errors in your layout xml files or AndroidManifest.xml file.
I noticed only some files have red under wavy line, check them carefully, especially which includes custom widgets like `lotteryanimationview`.

Comment: No there are no errors actually android studio showing all xml files incorrectly even the android manifest file.

Comment: This is how android studio showing android manifest file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item name="android.webkit.ClientCertRequest java.lang.String[] getKeyTypes()">
    <annotation name="android.support.annotation.Nullable" />
  </item>
  <item name="android.webkit.ClientCertRequest java.security.Principal[] getPrincipals()">
    <annotation name="android.support.annotation.Nullable" />
  </item>

Comment: In your question, you said: "Android studio suddenly showing autogenerated codes in xml files". In your comment, you said:  "there are no errors actually android studio showing all xml files incorrectly".  so which one is truth?

Comment: if i open xml files in android studio, it is showing autogenerated codes and errors but when i'm opening same file in editor like sublime text then it is showing correct xml code. That means same file showing different lines of code in android studio it is showing xml equivalent java code but in editor it is showing xml code that it is suppose to show. This is happening for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me once , i closed android studio and everything else that opened the same project folder (IDE , git GUI) then opened it again, xml files showed as they were supposed to.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes when an android studio working a long time. Reopen the project may help you.